# firebase functions - change status of record

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have using firebase cloud functions and twilio sms featuere..

this code works well but only I not understand how to update same record in realtime database

```
exports.textStatus = functions.database
       .ref('/sms_messages/{UID}').onCreate((change, event) => {

    const UID = event.params.UID;
    return admin.database().ref(`/sms_messages/${UID}`).once('value').then(snapshot => snapshot.val()).then(msg => {

                    const status      = msg.status
                    const phoneNumber = msg.number

                    // validate phone number
                    if ( !validE164(phoneNumber) ) {
                        throw new Error('number must be E164 format!')
                    }

                    const textMessage = {
                        body: `Velkommen til Club Nautic Booking. Du kan logge ind med ${status} og adgangskoden`,
                        to: phoneNumber,  // Text to this number
                        from: twilioNumber // From a valid Twilio number
                    }

                    return client.messages.create(textMessage)
                })
                .then(message => {
                    console.log(message.sid, 'success');;
                 })

                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
});
```

so if sms sent I want to update record in database status = sent (msg.status)

```
console.log(message.sid, 'success');
```

but have no idea how to get reference here and upedate same child node.. so status will be changed to sent or not sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// onCreate includes (snapshot, context)
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data
exports.textStatus = functions.database.ref('/sms_messages/{MSG_ID}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const MSG_ID = context.params.MSG_ID;
    // const msg = snapshot.val(); // Using Promise.resolve to retain catch()

    return Promise.resolve(snapshot.val())
      .then(msg => {

        const status = msg.status;
        const phoneNumber = msg.number;

        // validate phone number
        if (!validE164(phoneNumber)) {
          throw new Error('number must be E164 format!'); // This is reason for resolve
        }

        const textMessage = {
          body: `Velkommen til Club Nautic Booking. Du kan logge ind med ${status} og adgangskoden`,
          to: phoneNumber,  // Text to this number
          from: twilioNumber // From a valid Twilio number
        }

        return client.messages.create(textMessage);
      })
      .then(message => {
        console.log(message.sid, 'success');

        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DataSnapshot#ref
        return snapshot.ref.child('sent').set(true);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(MSG_ID, err);

        // sent sent to false, include error message for reference
        let error_promises = [
          snapshot.ref.child('sent').set(false),
          snapshot.ref.child('err_msg').set(err)
        ];
        return Promise.all(error_promises);

        // alternatively, just set to false
        // return snapshot.ref.child('sent').set(false);
      })
  });
```